# Python for .NET: passing byte[] to C# function

Tags: python, c#, python.net

I'm trying to call from python code C# functions from a dll using Python for .NET. Most things worked out of the box or I could figure them out from other posts, but the last thing that refuses to work is to pass a byte[] as a parameter.

Here's the C# function

```
    NCICoreConnCreateCmd (
        DestinationType type,           // enumeration
        DestinationParameter parameter, // enumeration
        byte[] val
        )
```

Here's the python code

```
    import COOT.Protocol.NCI.ControlMessage
    import COOT.Protocol.NCI.ControlMessage.Core

    # from System.Collections.Generic import List
    import System.Collections.Generic as C

    from System import Byte
    from System import Array

    t = COOT.Protocol.NCI.ControlMessage.DestinationType.NFCEE
    par = COOT.Protocol.NCI.ControlMessage.DestinationParameter.RFDiscoveryIdAndProtocol
    val = Array[Byte]([Byte(0), Byte(0)])
    cmd = COOT.Protocol.NCI.ControlMessage.Core.NCICoreConnCreateCmd(t, par, val)
```

And the error message,

```
TypeError: No constructor matches given arguments: (<class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'System.Byte[]'>)
```

Besides this issue, what about the method below? A more complicate 'List<(DestinationParameter parameter, byte[] val)>  list' parameter in the road.

```
NCICoreConnCreateCmd( DestinationType  type, List<(DestinationParameter parameter, byte[] val)>  list)
```

Any suggestion will be appreciate, thank you in advance.

Comment: According to the error message, it's looking for `int, int`, but you provided two enum classes.  You might try casting your enum values to `int` before calling the C# method.

Comment: No lucky, I change t & val to int, problem still exist.

Comment: Did you perform the cast, as I suggested?

Comment: yes, I change the last line to NCICoreConnCreateCmd(int(t), int(par), val).